# After updating Spyder to version 4.1.5 in Anaconda interface I can't launch Spyder any more

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

When I try to launch Spyder (in the Anaconda interface) I get an Application Launch error with the follwowing message (see below) --- the old version of Spyder 3.6.something) was running fine ...

Any hints on how I could get it running ??

Thanks !!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 205, in main
mainwindow.main()
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3651, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3526, in run_spyder
main.setup()
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 945, in setup
from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.plugin import IPythonConsole
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 46, in 
from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.widgets import (ClientWidget,
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\widgets\__init__.py", line 16, in 
from .debugging import DebuggingWidget
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\widgets\debugging.py", line 22, in 
from IPython.core.inputtransformer2 import TransformerManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython.core.inputtransformer2'
```

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry that you encountered this error. It was already reported and it'll be fixed in our next version (4.2.0), to be released in November 2020.

For now, please open the Anaconda Prompt and run there

`conda install ipython=7`

That should fix it.